# JQuery limit Images inside div

Tags: jquery, image, html, pagination

I am trying to upload some images and adding them div container.

My question is there are more than 1000's of images to upload so if I upload them to the same div  scrollbar is shown but it dosent looks good to my users.So I would like to add pagination to those images.

I found this [Site](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/)([example 5](http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/)) which suits my needs and In that it is actually containing a simple div and the structure is as follows:

```
 <div id="paginationdemo" class="demo">
                    <h1>Demo 5</h1>
                    <div id="p1" class="pagedemo _current" style="">Page 1</div>
                    <div id="p2" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 2</div>
                    <div id="p3" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 3</div>
                    <div id="p4" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 4</div>
                    <div id="p5" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 5</div>
                    <div id="p6" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 6</div>
                    <div id="p7" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 7</div>
                    <div id="p8" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 8</div>
                    <div id="p9" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 9</div>
                    <div id="p10" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">Page 10</div>
                    <div id="demo5">                   
                    </div>

 </div>
```

And it's script is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $("#demo5").paginate({
           count: 10,
           start: 1,
           display: 7,
           border: true,
           border_color: '#fff',
           text_color: '#fff',
           background_color: 'black',
           border_hover_color: '#ccc',
           text_hover_color: '#000',
           background_hover_color: '#fff',
           images: false,
           mouse: 'press',
           onChange: function (page) {
               $('._current', '#paginationdemo').removeClass('_current').hide();
               $('#p' + page).addClass('_current').show();
           }
       });
   });

    </script>
```

This is how I upload Images dynamically

```
 $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                    $('#p1').append("<img class='LoadclickImage' align='left' style='height:48px;width:75px;' src='Uploads/" + file.name + "' width='75' height='50'  href='Uploads/" + file.name + "' >");
                });
```

Now what happens is if I add Images they are appending to the same page and the list is going on increasing so how do I limit the images to the specific div and add them to the next page by creating it dynamcally as I don't know how many mages they will upload and try to append them to the next page if they exceed.

And if anyone has a better and the simplest idea they can share.I love to hear them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it (but assuming all the images are going to be loaded at the same time in just one ajax request).

```
<div id="paginationdemo" class="demo">
    <h1>Demo 5</h1>
    <div id="pagesContainer">
        <div id="p1" class="pagedemo _current"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo5"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var imagesPerPage = 4, pageNumber = 1;

function onAjaxSucceded(data) {
    var pagesContainer = $('#pagesContainer'),
        imagesInPage = 0,
        divPage = $("#p1");

    $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {
        if (imagesInPage >= imagesPerPage) {
            imagesInPage = 1;
            pageNumber += 1;
            divPage = $('<div/>', {id : "p" + pageNumber}).addClass('pagedemo').hide().appendTo(pagesContainer);
        } else {
            imagesInPage += 1;
        }
        var src = 'Uploads/' + file.name;
        $('<img>', {src: src, href: src, "class": 'LoadclickImage', align: 'left'}).appendTo(divPage);
    });

    $("#demo5").paginate({
        count: pageNumber,
        start: 1,
        display: Math.min(7, pageNumber),
        border: true,
        border_color: '#fff',
        text_color: '#fff',
        background_color: 'black',
        border_hover_color: '#ccc',
        text_hover_color: '#000',
        background_hover_color: '#fff',
        images: false,
        mouse: 'press',
        onChange: function(page) {
            $('#paginationdemo ._current').removeClass('_current').hide();
            $('#p' + page).addClass('_current').show();
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/gbzsR/7/

Comment: @proton-Thanks for your reply.When I tried with your code it adds a new page and it adds the image to the newly added page.Suppose If I select 5 images at a time all the 5 images needs to add to the same page.If it is greater than 5 I need to append the rest of the selected images to the next page which needs to be created dynamically.

Comment: @DotNetter I updated my code to use a statically created first page (I suppose that is what you are asking).

Comment: @proton-You're really awesome.Really you don't know how much time you save me today.Thanks once again cheers:)

Comment: @proton-Last doubt that how do I remove the appended page.As If I remove and load it just adding to a new page and adding to them.So I would like to delete the entire pages and add them again if they remove.

Comment: @DotNetter Your original question has being answered so please open another question. I cannot understand this one about removing and re-adding pages. Try to explain more about what you need with examples and adding what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have done that already and here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077197/remove-inactive-class-items

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to control which "page" div to append the image to.  You are already appending the images in a loop, so you're halfway there.

There might be a way do this all through the jQuery selector, but I don't have that much jQuery kung-foo.  So, I'm using an html attribute to keep track if the "page" div is full.

In my code, I'm appending

tags and using a set number.  It was easier to test this way, but there's no difference to the main logic.

Here is my HTML...

```
<div id="p1" full="no" class="pagedemo _current" style="">Page 1</div>
<div id="p2" full="no" class="pagedemo">Page 2</div>
<div id="p3" full="no" class="pagedemo">Page 3</div>
<div id="p4" full="no" class="pagedemo">Page 4</div>
<div id="p5" full="no" class="pagedemo">Page 5</div>
<div id="p6" full="no" class="pagedemo">Page 6</div>
```

And this is my script...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var images = 65;

        for(var i = 1; i <= images; i++)
        {
            var page = $('.pagedemo[full="no"]').first();

            $(page).append("<p>" + i + "</p>");

            if ($(page).children("p").length == 10)
            {
                $(page).attr('full', 'yes');
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: @Trent-Thanks for helping me.I appreciate your work but somehow I couldn't get it worked :(