# Remove inactive class items

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, pagination

I am trying to make a `pagination` as shown below by uploading images and adding them to a container by creating new `div` with new `id's` and giving `class` as `current` for the first page.

If I change to the new page I remove the active class to the current page and add it to the selected page.

I would like to know how do I remove all the `inactive` pages which do not have class "current"

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imagesPerPage = 4, pageNumber = 1;

function onAjaxSucceded(data) {
    var pagesContainer = $('#pagesContainer'),
        imagesInPage = 0,
        divPage = $("#p1");

    $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {
        if (imagesInPage >= imagesPerPage) {
            imagesInPage = 1;
            pageNumber += 1;
            divPage = $('<div/>', {id : "p" + pageNumber}).addClass('pagedemo').hide().appendTo(pagesContainer);
        } else {
            imagesInPage += 1;
        }
        var src = 'Uploads/' + file.name;
        $('<img>', {src: src, href: src, "class": 'LoadclickImage', align: 'left'}).appendTo(divPage);
    });

    $("#demo5").paginate({
        count: pageNumber,
        start: 1,
        display: Math.min(7, pageNumber),
        border: true,
        border_color: '#fff',
        text_color: '#fff',
        background_color: 'black',
        border_hover_color: '#ccc',
        text_hover_color: '#000',
        background_hover_color: '#fff',
        images: false,
        mouse: 'press',
        onChange: function(page) {
            $('#paginationdemo ._current').removeClass('_current').hide();
            $('#p' + page).addClass('_current').show();
        }
    });
}

var fakeAjaxData = {
    result: [
        {name: '../../../img/keys.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/logo.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/input-button-bg.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/remove-resources.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/logo.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/input-button-bg.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/remove-resources.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/keys.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/keys.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/input-button-bg.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/logo.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/remove-resources.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/keys.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/keys.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/input-button-bg.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/logo.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/remove-resources.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/input-button-bg.png'},
        {name: '../../../img/logo.png'},
    ]
};

$(function() {
    onAjaxSucceded(fakeAjaxData);
});
</script>
```

Here's my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbzsR/24/)

**EDIT**:

Instead of `removing` `inactive` class can anyone say me how do I remove all the pages and If I add again I need to add images from the `1st page.` as of now If I remove the pages it's adding from the last page it has added.

Excuse me if my tags are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#pagesContainer > :not(._current)").remove()
```

Comment: @mikez-First thanks for your reply.It still dosen't delete pages.

Comment: I am not sure what to do. I am not familiar with the paginate plugin.

Comment: +1 This code does what @DotNetter asked. The only problem I see in OP's demo is that he is attaching the click event outside before all the DOM has loaded and so the delete button does nothing when clicked. See the demo updated: http://jsfiddle.net/gbzsR/30/

Comment: @Protron-In the fiddle it dosen't do anything even now even if it is in DOM.

Comment: @DotNetter I just tested again, and if I click it and, then go to any other page, the other page is not shown anymore. Because the whole div for the rest of the pages and their respective images are not part of the page anymore. But maybe that is not what you want (but I still don't know what you really want).

Comment: Ah! Sorry for that its deleting the pages and leaving the page numbers and I want to remove the page numbers as the inactive class has been applied for them.If I add Images again it adds from the last page(ie. suppose if two pages are added before then its adding from the third page.So I want to remove the page numbers and show it from the starting page.